# Deleting pointers in non pointer vector

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, destructor

I'll post a screenshot of code because also want to show the variables while debugging.
Screenshot:

[image]

Ok, so I have the code as on the screenshot and:

```
SystemClass *pSystemClass = new SystemClass();
// Use of pSystemClas
delete pSystemClass;
```

And the question, do I have to remove the pointers that are stored in vp_DatabaseManager vector before deleting pSystemClass or can I do it in SystemClass destructor as it is shown on the screenshot?

Because in the debug mode it looks like the vp_DatabaseManager vector is deleted before I can access the pointers in SystemClass destructor.

Comment: please post the code here, and not some jpeg. it is easier to copy/paste/analyze/read

Comment: Ok, problem is solved, but also added the code here.

Comment: @So_ Please do not edit answers into the question. I have rolled back the question. Instead, accept a posted answer. If you want to show that code then post it as an Answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `SystemClass` destructor, iterate through the `vector` and delete the pointers. You can also research `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you, after you answered I looked at the debugger again and it looks like I had break point in a wrong place(bracket), this is why I was confused by locals in debug window.